# how to set position of textview

Tags: android, animation, textview, gravity

I want to set my  my text under the center of my view.
I know that I need to do it with Gravity but still dont see the right result
I just wanted to do Animation that starts from under the center and go left right and return to started position 
My code is

```
        setContentView(R.layout.logo);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLabel);
    mLayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
        mLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
        mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_X_SHIFT/2); 
        mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_Y_SHIFT/2-Gravity.AXIS_Y_SHIFT/3); 
        mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(100f, -100f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
        mAnimation.setDuration(2000); 
        mTextView.setAnimation(mAnimation);

        mAnimation.start();
```

and the xml looks like:

```
 <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:flipInterval="2000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip" >
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/Linear"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/logonews"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Israel News"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

     />

  </LinearLayout>
  </ViewFlipper>
```

thanks for help

Comment: solved ur issue or stil facing

Answer (score 1):

When do you want the Animation to play?

What result are you seeing instead?

If you want it to play immediately, use `startAnimation` instead of `setAnimation`.

Edit:  Looking at your code in light of the comments you made...

If you want your `TextView` to be below your logo image, you'll need to remove the background drawable from the `LinearLayout`, change its orientation to vertical, and put the image into an `ImageView` instead, before your `TextView` in the `LinearLayout`.  This allows Android to lay them out in order...

Like this:

```
 <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:flipInterval="2000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip" >
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/Linear"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/logonews"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Israel News"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

     />

  </LinearLayout>
  </ViewFlipper>
```

or if you need the image to be the background you can create an empty View above the `TextView` that's the same size as the image.

Comment: the animation is working but not as I want it. I have a logo that is my background and is on the center of screen. and I want that my text view will be under the logo,like to set some position to start the animation place of text view

Comment: You can use an animation resource to chain animations together using `<set>`.  See here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html  If I understand you correctly, you can chain multiple translations together for the effect you want.

Comment: why when I use mTextView.setGravity(Gravity.AXIS_Y_SHIFT/2-Gravity.AXIS_Y_SHIFT/3);  its on the bottom of the view even the animation is canceled

Answer (score 0):

- 1st, Gravity attribute has effects on the postion of text content in TextView, not the TextView.
- 2nd, TranslateAnimation moves straightly only once. it will not move back and forward, so you may need combine several TranslateAnimation to implements what you want.
- 3rd, user startAnimation.

Comment: how can I put mt textunder the center of screen with setGravit?

Comment: use `RelativeLayout`, put the `ImageView` in its center by setting `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` and then let the `TextVie` under `ImageView`.